# Password reset email

Tags: email

I have a personal org where I used to try my trailhead challenges. Few days back I was getting email from Salesforce org about job I had been running on my personal email id. I opted for not receiving these emails so I went into salesforce > setup > email > email deliverability and I set email to - no email instead of system email only. And Now I have forgotten password to my org and I cannot receive password reset email from Salesforce.

What Can I do? I cannot go inside the org anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second org and then contact Salesforce Support through your second org providing your User Id. If they can validate you are the legitimate owner of the org you need access to, they can try to help.

Comment: I have another trailhead org where I can login. Does that help?

Comment: Yea, log in and click "help" at the top right and submit a case

Comment: I will give it a try